# SQL string comparison

Tags: sql

These are my table's columns:

```
contact_id, contact_number
```

I have one number to search in that table `contactInfo`.

I have such type of entries in my table

```
contact_id    contact_number
1             1234567890
2             2345678901
```

and `numberToSearch` may be in any such format `+911234567890` or simply `1234567890`

I am using this query

```
Select * from contactInfo where contact_number like numberToSearch;
```

This query works correctly when both `contact_number` and `numberToSearch` are same. 
But when `numberToSearch` is larger than `contact_number` then it does not find the number.

Please suggest me what should I do to match this pattern? Last digit of `numberToFind` must match with `contact_number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `numberToSearch` is a *longer* version of the number that includes contact number as a substring, I think you want your search condition to be the other way around:

```
Select * from contactInfo where numberToSearch like '%'+contact_number+'%';
```

This SQL Server version. In Oracle or MySQL use `CONCAT('%', contact_number, '%')`

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for the number that is in number to search string then you have to write query like following

```
Select * from contactInfo where contact_number like '%numberToSearch%';
```